# Filter data in ListView [mvvm]

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, filter

I have created a listview (in xaml), where I have used GridViewColumn with DisplayMemberBinding to show properties of my ViewModel.

```
     <ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContent}">
        <ListView.View>
           <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}"/>
              <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
           </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
     </ListView>
```

Everything works fine. I can see the content of DataContent in my listview.
Now I want to have a kind of listview filter. The user can enter in a textbox a string which is currently searched in every item in DataContent. 
The items in DataContent have a boolean property named "IsShown". This property is set to false, when the entered string is not found in the property "UserName" otherwise true.

What I need now is:
Every row in the listview, which does not have a matching UserName must be hidden.
I think I can use here somehow the property IsShown (in view model), which is available for each row.
When the user removes or changes the string from the textbox the content of DataContent is searched again and IsShown is modified if necessary.
The listview must be updated again. Only the rows are shown, where "IsShown" is true.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of CollectionView class

[See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx)

as well specific filter example

[Filter Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752348.aspx)

Comment: thank you I will check this. Seems to be the solution for my problem.